# Why does my app close when swiping tabs in ViewPager? (Only on Huawei devices)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs, huawei-mobile-services

This happens only on Huawei devices (except honor 5x). This is the app (Music Player): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ms.musicplayer

Code for ViewPager and Tabs:

```
// Viewpager setup
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

        // Tabs
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new myAdapter(fragmentManager));

        if (tabLayout != null) {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
```

XML for Tabs:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="4dp"

            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"

            app:tabTextColor="@color/transparetWhiteFifty"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/tabBGColor"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteFifty"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

I have checked the phone with other music players with ViewPager and there's no problem.

Comment: Do you see anything relevant in the LogCat ? Could you add the stacktrace of the crash, if there is one ?

Comment: Try to test with some more device about the issue. In some phone its happens due to memory issue. I faced similar issue in one phone but rest work fine.

Comment: @JonasCz It doesn't show any ANR. It's just that app exits to homescreen. Hence, no logcat :/

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot Yes, It happens only with Huawei honor 4X. Nobody else has reported this issue. But the issue is, why doesn't this happen with other apps with ViewPager?

Comment: try to get some stack trace for that in next app upload.